COUNTA counting blanks in one case, not in another
I have two workbooks that use COUNTA, to count if there is a value throughout the row
The basic formula in B1:
=IF($A1="","",COUNTA($C1:$G1))

Cells in C through G have a data validation drop down list of blank space, "Y", "N".
In the 1st workbook, COUNTA will count the cell if the blank space has been selected from the list. Thanks to this solution, I know it requires subtracting COUNTBLANK.
But in my second workbook, the COUNTA, with the same drop downs, will treat the blank space from the list as truly nothing, not including it in the count. See example:

To summarize: In my 1st workbook, if I select blank space, COUNTA counts the cell anyways, requiring COUNTBLANK. But in my 2nd workbook, it doesn't.
What is going on here? Why the discrepancy? Thanks.

Mostly likely you have empty cells, not cells with "" in them.

Try =IF($A1="","",COLUMNS($C1:$G1)-COUNTBLANK($C1:$G1)) if you want to treat blank cells the same as cells containing (showing) Nothing. The latter are cells that e.g. contain ="" or ': they are not blank i.e. ISBLANK() returns FALSE.

=IF(LEN(A1),SUM(N(LEN(C1:G1)>0)),"")

In the first workbook, could you please select the cells with --,Yes,No dropdown and choose Circle Invalid Data from the toolbar? It will help to spot the ones that are not blank.
